# Python: High(er) precision for complex numbers - math.e**(pi*1j)

Tags: python, precision, complex-numbers

My code for Eulers identity gives this precision:

```
math.e**(pi*1j)
>> (-1+1.22464679915e-16j)
```

Is there a way to "adjust" the precision to say Xe-30?
And is there a way to round to nearest Xe-10 for example?

I tried `mpf(math.e**(pi*1j))` to specify mp.prec = 30 --> this gives me an error, probably because complex numbers can't be converted to float. ("Cannot create mpg from -1+1.22...e-16j")

Thanks in advance for all helpful people out there!

Comment: The complex number is composed of two `float`s, but you are constrained by the precision offered by your machine. You need a library that represents real numbers using something other than machine `float`s, similar to how Python doesn't simply use machine  `int`s to represent integers.

Comment: [Python `mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/)?